# Decribing pop in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I am studying up on IA32. When I think about what the `popl DEST` instruction is doing I think the following:

```
movl (%esp), DEST
addl $4, %esp
```

But then I started second guessing myself when I thought about `popl %esp`. Even though that is probably a pointless instruction, I think there is probably a better way to think of generally describing the `popl DEST` instruction. How would you describe it?

Comment: I'm sorry that someone did not find my question useful. Please feel free to comment on it so that I can improve questions in the future.

Comment: The `add` instruction modifies the status flags. Therefore `lea esp, [esp + 4]` would be a better match to what `pop` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a small portion of the pseudo code for the POP instruction from Intel's documentation:

```
IF StackAddrSize = 32
  THEN
    IF OperandSize = 32
      THEN
        DEST ← SS:ESP; (* Copy a doubleword *)
        ESP ← ESP + 4;
      ELSE (* OperandSize = 16*)
        ...
    FI;
...
```

But here's what it says specifically about `POP xSP`:

> The POP ESP instruction increments the stack pointer (ESP) before data at the old top of stack is written into the destination.

This means that the sequence

```
PUSH ESP
POP ESP
```

does nothing out of ordinary, just like this one:

```
PUSH EAX
POP EAX
```

Similarly, there's some text on `PUSH xSP`:

> The PUSH ESP instruction pushes the value of the ESP register as it existed before the instruction was executed. If a PUSH instruction uses a memory operand in which the ESP register is used for computing the operand address, the address of the operand is computed before the ESP register is decremented.

Comment: So it looks like the way I chose to describe it is just like the documentation from Intel. There is just a special note for `pop %esp` that says that it increments the stack pointer first.

Comment: @KyleWeller: Indeed.  Intel could have written pseudo-code that actually matched the behaviour of `pop esp` and `push esp`, but for some reason chose not too.  It's barely more complicated than the current pseudo-code, just adding a temporary.  [What is an assembly-level representation of pushl/popl %esp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69489798)